# Loading CSV gives weird format

Tags: python, postgresql, dbeaver

When loading a csv (extracted from a database), I get this weird format:

```
'{"{\\"size\\": \\"medium\\", \\"text\\": \\"foo\\", \\"type\\": \\"header\\"}","{\\"text\\": \\"bar\\\\n\\", \\"type\\": \\"text\\"}",,"{\\"text\\": \\"•\\\\trandom text foo bar random random \\\\"\\\\n\\\\n"\\", \\"type\\": \\"text\\"}"
```

When directly querying the database with python, it returns a normal format, which I can read as a json. I suspect it has something to do in what format the file is extracted or with what kind of character formatting, but I'm not sure what to look for. Can someone explain to me what is going on and how to avoid this?

Many thanks!

Comment: Which dbms? How do you load?

Comment: I extracted it with DBeaver, from a postgresql db

Comment: it can be normal string - you have `" "` with another `"` inside and this `"` needs \ to thread `"` as normal char, not end of string. And because \  may have special meaning in some tools so it has to put \\ to treats it as normal char instead of special char. So it is `escaped` string and Python need it to thread it as correct JSON.

Comment: it seems `postgresql` has special functions to work with JSON string - see [json](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/functions-json.html). For example `to_json` converts `'Fred said "Hi."` to `"Fred said \"Hi.\"`. And you would need some `from_json` but I don't see it on this page.

Comment: Thanks Furas. I find it hard to avoid these problems or to find a solution. I lost many frustrating hours today because I tried to load the csv, which broke my code. Querying it with python > extract it to csv > load csv in other script also breaks it. I tried the escape char while loading csv, but this also didn't do anything. So there's something going on here :)